# Max, Min and sum Random Number php

Tags: php

Here's the code

```
<?php
echo "<table border=\"0\">";
for ($d = 1; $d <= $times;$d++ )
 {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo  rand(1,6), "\n";
echo "</td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table>"; ?>
```

I'm trying to get the max,min and sum of the `rand(1,6), "\n";`
But i can't figure it out. And it's killing me.

Comment: "I'm trying" --- how exactly?

Comment: put the results in an array, from there its easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect the random numbers in an array, too:

```
echo "<table border=\"0\">";
$rands = array();
#################
for ($d = 1; $d <= $times; $d++)
{
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $rands[] = rand(1,6), "\n"; 
         ###########
    echo "</td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table>"; ?>
```

Afterwards you can make use of  [`max`](http://php.net/max), [`min`](http://php.net/min) and [`array_sum`](http://php.net/array_sum) (all these links come with nice examples).

As your code already shows you should start to differ between code that does data-processing and code that does the HTML output:

```
// handle the data

$randomNumbers = array();
foreach (range(1, $times) as $d)
{
    $randomNumbers[$d] = rand(1,6);
}


// output the data

echo '<table border="0">';
foreach ($randomNumbers as $number) {
    printf("<tr><td>%d</tr></td>", $number);
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$rands = array(); // rand() storage
for($d = 1; $d <= $times; $d++){
    $rands[$d] = rand(1, 6); // store rands
}
var_dump($min = min($rands)); // min() of rands
var_dump($min = max($rands)); // max() of rands
```

^ see sample code.

(**PS**: I use `[$d]` as he has a 1-based increment and it may be needed for his further logic. This way the rands keys match his $d and can be easily accessed later on.)

Comment: $rands[] = rand(1, 6); // $d not needed

Comment: @zerkms To stay within his logic. He uses 1-based increment. So if he will walk the array, the key will be 1-off. I'm playing by his rules.

Comment: @Claudrian: there is a `foreach` to iterate over arrays

Comment: the OP does nothing with $d, so you could start at 50billion if you wanted

Comment: @Dagon I play chess and I see the bigger picture. He may have issues later on with the offsets as he increments in a peculiar way (1- based). Just trust me...

Comment: @Claudrian: or you could teach OP that 0-based arrays is the "right" way to do it.

Comment: Sometimes you need 0 based, other times you need 1 based. Like... bind statement params in PDO, 1 based.

Comment: "Like... bind statement params in PDO" --- are you sure?

Comment: @zerkms RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php "this will be the 1-indexed position of the parameter".

Comment: @Claudrian: it has nothing to do with arrays. The arrays in PDO bindings are still 0-based (see `execute()`)

Comment: @zerkms I'm stopping here. It's got to do with the arguments but it's still 1 based... Btw, PHP does not have arrays, they're maps if we want to be specific.

Comment: @Claudrian: omg, for the user it doesn't matter what underlying container is used. For 99% users to be array - it should implement all array related interfaces and behave like array. Anyway, 1-based arrays are more harm than good usually.

Comment: @zerkms With that I agree! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$min = 10;
$max = -1;
$sum = 0;

for ($d = 1; $d <= $times; $d++) {
    $n = rand(1, 6);
    if ($n < $min) $min = $n;
    if ($n > $max) $max = $n;
    $sum += $n;
}

echo $min . ' ' . $max . ' ' . $sum . '<br/>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum=0; 
for ($d = 1; $d <= $times;$d++ ) { 
  echo "<tr><td>";  
  $r=rand(1,6);
  $sum +=$r;
  echo  "$r, \n"; 
  echo "</td></tr>"; 
  if ($d==1) { $min=$r; $max=$r; } 
  if ($r>$max) $max=$r;
  if ($r<$min) $min=$r;
} 
// do something with $min, $max and $sum;
```

Comment: Without `$min` and `$max` initialization - the code in this answer is terrible

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php      
  $total = 0;
  echo "<table border=\"0\">";

  for ($d = 1; $d <= $times;$d++ )
  { 
       $rand = rand(1,6);
       $total += $rand;    
       $array[] = $rand;

       echo "<tr><td>";
       echo  $rand, "\n";
       echo "</td></tr>";
  } 
echo "</table>"; ?>

echo $total;
echo min($array);
echo max($array);
```